# Datagridview ability to modify data or other alternates

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I am using a SQlite database connected to datagridview control. Now, I am able to display the database in the Winforms application. My next requirements are to read the items in the datagridview and then group different rows together based on whats in it.. So, if there are two rows matched by an alarm id, I want both the rows to be next to each other with some id flag or colorcode. Is it possible to do this... Ideally would like the row to get listed in a tree like structure , like how windows explorer handles directories... Is this possible or anything close to is possible?

Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible is a loaded question. In Hollywood, anything is possible.

If you mean "is it possible for .NET to automagically group things for me so I don't have to code anything", the answer is no. There are third party controls, however, that can do an amount of nesting, if you feed them the data and give them the nesting rules. They are not free, but can save you a lot of time.

Sans buying, as long as you can figure out how to sort in the proper order for your grouping, you can easily make them nest in a tree control. You can also have a grid in a grid and do some really neat nesting.

If you merely want the rows next to each other and use alternative colors each time an alarm changes, you can do this. Sort the data first and then you can bind to a grid (as an example, not THE example) and alter background color using the Row Binding event. Even with a treeview, you can intercept the individual binding events.

Does any of this make sense? If not, I suggest reading up on the controls in question, as that will lead you to an answer.

The first place to start is figure out the order for the data so you can group properly.

Comment: The problem is its very hard to group using a code. Its is something that the user must do by seeing the contents of a row because the contents are not always specific to a particular pattern... The idea is I should have a control(when i right click) that gives me an option to group to another line. When I group it, it should be right below the line i grouped it to... ??

Comment: Ordering is the first step to grouping, so I would conquer that (either in the query or through a filter in code) first. After that, you have options on setting up the code to group things.

Comment: Making myself sure,  there isnt any way to group two rows that arent next to each other  right ? Because I need to come up with some very complicated queries to order them.